# continuing service after app is removed from recent apps

Tags: android, android-service

I am running android 7.0. I created a service that shows a toast after 10 seconds. I want it to show the toast even after I have swiped right on the recent apps list.

Here is the code for my service:

```
public class DelayedMessageService extends IntentService{

    public static final String EXTRA_MESSAGE = "message";
    private Handler handler;

    public DelayedMessageService(){
        super("DelayedMessageService");
    }

    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId){
        handler = new Handler();
        return super.onStartCommand(intent, flags, startId);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {
        synchronized (this){
            try{
                wait(10000);
            }catch (InterruptedException e){
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        String text = intent.getStringExtra(EXTRA_MESSAGE);
        showText(text);
    }


    private void showText(final String text){
        handler.post(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), text, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

How do I make it show the Toast even after I remove it from the recent apps list.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Just implement `onDestroy` method and stop the service in it.

Comment: May i see your code where you call to start the service ?

Comment: This is the code to start the service:

Comment: public void onClick(View view){
        Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, DelayedMessageService.class);
        intent.putExtra(DelayedMessageService.EXTRA_MESSAGE, getResources().getString(R.string.button_response));
        startService(intent);
    }

Comment: Please check my answer, hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

You must implement `onDestroy` method in you `MainActivity` class. And then just stop your service.

```
@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    Intent myService = new Intent(MainActivity.this, DelayedMessageService.class);
    stopService(myService);
}
```

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

You can't display a toast when the app is not active, maybe you should try performing some other action e.g Notification. It requires your app to be running to show. And you can't make a toast inside your service.